# Can I order parts that are painted stock colors?

Tags: nissan, parts

I'm trying to order a fuel door for my 2006 Altima on http://www.nissanpartsdirect.com but they don't ask for a color. Where can I go to get a new fuel door that's painted the same color as my car? I have no desire to paint it myself.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, wouldn't that part come not painted or just with primer?

Comment: Modified a bit to ask a better question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most if not all of those type parts are paint to match. If you call the dealer they should be able to give you a price quote painted. Our parts department would send it over to our body shop for it to be painted before you picked it up. There is an additional charge for this however.

You may also want to check your local salvage yards as it may be more economical to purchase one from them.

Comment: Salvage yard is a good idea. I was planning on checking the net first and then finding a salvaged part if I could get one for a deal. Thanks for the feedback